# Optimal way to build and fill a distance matrix using Google Maps API

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

Say I have a distance matrix like so

```
           | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
--------------------------------------------------|
Location 1 |            |            |            |
Location 2 |            |            |            |
Location 3 |            |            |            |
```

I want to hit the Google Maps API to fill this out. Like so:

```
           | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
--------------------------------------------------|
Location 1 | 0 min      | 6-10 min   | 12-18 min  |
Location 2 | 6-10 min   | 0 min      | 8-12 min   |
Location 3 | 12-18 min  | 8-12 min   | 0 min      |
```

I know I can hit their [distance matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to get this information but their examples are pretty terse.

So as an example, say I have ~50 locations for which will traverse the columns and rows. Can I hit their API such that

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json
?origins=Location 1|Location 2|Location 3
&destinations=Location 1|Location 2| Location 3
&mode=driving
&traffic_model=optimistic
&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And then would I expect to receive my `JSON` object and parse it out to fill my table appropriately?

Basically my question boils down to

> How many origins and destinations am I limited to in a single request with the Distance Matrix? And would I be formatting my URL appropriately for 60+ origins and destinations if so?